# Changing Sitecore predefined language display name

Tags: multilingual

Is it possible to change Sitecore's predefined language names?

For example, French languages look like this:

```
French (Belgium) : français (Belgique)
French (Canada) : français (Canada)
French (Switzerland) : français (Suisse)
French (France) : français (France)
French (Luxembourg) : français (Luxembourg)
French (Monaco) : français (Monaco)
```

Is it possible to capitalize *français* somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: It comes from .NET/Windows globalization. But just for the point's sake - you actually should not capitalize the language term "français". https://www.thoughtco.com/use-of-french-capitalization-4085543 and https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/fr-fran%C3%A7ais-fran%C3%A7ais-majuscule-minuscule.320012/

Comment: @MarkCassidy Many thanks. I've looked into it after your comment and I believe you're right. If you post this as an answer I'll accept it as worked for me perfectly.